# POP3 protocol how to get mail twice

Tags: c#, email, pop3

I have tested with GMail, (pop.gmail.com) if i get all message from pop server, for a certain time interval or till i receive new mail, i can't get all mails again (i mean form the same client, if i try to get mails more than once i get this issue).

I have tried to configure my GMail box but there are no change, is that behaviour an aspect of POP3's protocol or is a GMail's policy? 
I have the same issue to my customer's mailbox and would like to solve it, is there a way to configure his mail box so that i can get all mails every time i looking for them?

If no is the answer, i haven't choice and i need to change my businsess logic, but if possibile i would like to avoid it.

PS : the command i use to check if there are mail to download (this command didn't work the second time i invoke it) is the command STAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, GMail's POP3 server does not behave like standard POP3 servers and hides messages from clients.

If you want to configure your GMail POP3 settings to behave the way POP3 is intended to behave according to their protocol specifications, you'll need to log in to your GMail account via your web browser and navigate to the `Forwarding and POP/IMAP` tab of your `GMail Settings` page and set your `POP Download` options to look like this:

[X] Enable POP for **all mail** (even mail that's already been downloaded)

Answer (score 1):

Most POP clients have an option to "Leave mail on server" that stops them from deleting a message after it is read.

Comment: yes and that is not a problem, the problem is that the first time i connect to the serve i use STAT to count messages in my inbox.
With that numer i know how to enumerate all the mail, then i disconnect for few minutes.
Later (about five minute) i connect again and check the number of the messages (using command STAT) now the messages are 0, but i would like to see all the messages like the first time i run algorithm,
After few hours (about two) or if a new mail incoming i can see all messages again.

I have the same issue when using gmail, this let me think is some kind of convetion.